# Mean value $E(2^X)$

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable and the distribution of $X$ is a Poisson distribution with $\lambda$ parameter. We know that mean value $E(X) = \lambda$, but what we can say about $E(2^X)$?

Comment: I can't understand. What do you mean by $E(X)=2^X$?

Comment: Maybe you want to calculate $E(2^X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to know what we can say about $E[2^X]$.

For each measurable function g for a given rv X with density $f_X$ we can calculate $E[g(X)]$ by $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_X(x) dx$$
In the discrete case this leads to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(k) P(X=k)$$

In your case is $g(x) = 2^x$

What's $P(X=k)$ if $X$ is a poisson distribution?

Comment: Uhm... What is it?

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata $P(X=k)=\lambda^k\cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$. See wiki

Comment: @callculus I get it! Thanks!